# SQLITE table is not inserting default value

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-sqlite

In my project, I am trying to insert data into SQLITE table. Insert is working fine but if I didn't pass any value from my activity then I can see null values inside the table, instead of default value. Any help is appreciated.

**Language**

```
Kotlin
```

**Code**

```
    var CREATE_NOTE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT," +
            KEY_QUANTITY + " INTEGER DEFAULT 1," +
            KEY_NOTE + " TEXT DEFAULT GOOD," +
            KEY_PRICE + " DOUBLE" +
            ")"

fun insertData(name: String, quantity: String, note: String, price:Double)
{
    val db=this.writableDatabase
    var cv=ContentValues()

    cv.put(KEY_NAME,name.trim())
    cv.put(KEY_QUANTITY,quantity.trim())
    cv.put(KEY_NOTE,note)
    cv.put(KEY_PRICE,price)

    val result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv)

}
```

Comment: I believe you would need to not have `cv.put(KEY_QUANTITY,quantity.trim())` if there was no value. So try placing the line in an if clause so that it only runs if there is a value in **quantity**.

Comment: Thanks @MikeT for your comment but I tried that too. Its still not working.   
    if(itemquantity.trim().equals(null))
            {
                cv.put(KEY_QUANTITY,1)
            }
            else
            {
                cv.put(KEY_QUANTITY,quantity.trim())
            }

Comment: I don't believe that it would ever be null, try checking the length and only include if the length is greater than 0.  (you could just temporarily remove the cv.put to show that without it does provide the default value).

Comment: I can see two spaces between : and Hello is my value. "Value of Quantity is:  HELLO"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following will work :-

```
fun insertData(name: String, quantity: String, note: String, price:Double)
{
    val db=this.writableDatabase
    var cv=ContentValues()

    cv.put(KEY_NAME,name.trim())
    if (quantity.trim().length > 0) {
        cv.put(KEY_QUANTITY,quantity.trim())
    }
    cv.put(KEY_NOTE,note)
    cv.put(KEY_PRICE,price)

    val result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv)
}
```

Thus if there is an empty string i.e. "" after the trim (), then the length will be 0 and thus the line `cv.put(KEY_QUANTITY,quantity.trim())` will not execute.

The subtle difference is that if you used `cv.put(KEY_QUANTITY,quantity.trim())` when quantity was "" "      " etc then the underlying generated SQL would inlcude the quantity column (KEY_QUANTITY) and assign a value. Something like

```
INSERT INTO your_table (name,quantity,note,price) VALUES(?,?,?,?);
```

- The ?'s would be replaced by the values.

However, without the line then the INSERT would be :-

```
INSERT INTO your_table (name,note,price) VALUES(?,?,?);
```

Therefore as there is no attempt to assign a value to the quantity column, then the DEFAULT value will be used for the quatity column.

- Note the above is in-principle code and hasn't been tested so it may contain some errors.

### Working Example

using the following code the above works as expected :-

**MainActivity.kt** :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var dbhlpr = DBHelper(this);
        dbhlpr.insertData("Test","","test",10.34)
        dbhlpr.insertData("Test2","100","test2", 34.67)
        var csr = dbhlpr.writableDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null,null,null,null,null,null)
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr)

    }
```

**DBHelper.kt** :-

```
internal class DBHelper(context: Context) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION) {

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {

        val crt_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT," +
                KEY_QUANTITY + " INTEGER DEFAULT 1," +
                KEY_NOTE + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_PRICE + " REAL" +
                ")"
        db.execSQL(crt_sql);

    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, i: Int, i1: Int) {

    }

    fun insertData(name: String, quantity: String, note: String, price:Double)
    {
        val db=this.writableDatabase
        var cv= ContentValues()

        cv.put(KEY_NAME,name.trim())
        if (quantity.trim().length > 0) {
            cv.put(KEY_QUANTITY,quantity.trim())
        }
        cv.put(KEY_NOTE,note)
        cv.put(KEY_PRICE,price)

        val result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv)
    }

    companion object {

        val DBNAME = "mydb"
        val DBVERSION = 1
        val TABLE_NAME = "mytable"
        val KEY_ID = BaseColumns._ID
        val KEY_NAME = "name"
        val KEY_QUANTITY = "quantity"
        val KEY_NOTE = "note"
        val KEY_PRICE = "price"
    }
}
```

#### Result (first row uses default, 2nd doesn't)

```
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@268ba35
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out: 0 {
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out:    _id=1
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out:    name=Test
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out:    quantity=1
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out:    note=test
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out:    price=10.34
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out: }
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out: 1 {
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out:    _id=2
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out:    name=Test2
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out:    quantity=100
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out:    note=test2
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out:    price=34.67
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out: }
2019-01-05 13:43:04.486 1952-1952/so54048348.kotlinso54048348 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

Comment: @Test have you changed the table definition since originally running the App? If so try deleting the App's data or uninstalling the App and rerunning. Any changes will not be applied as the **onCreate** method only runs when the database is created, that is **onCreate** once (automatically) for the lifetime of the database.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, It worked after uninstalling and installing the app.